# HTML Canvas As Overlayview In Google Maps

Tags: html, google-maps, canvas

Are there any examples of a google map that has one big canvas as an overlayview. I'm having a hard time positioning the canvas whenever the map zoom or pans.

Comment: This is not quite an answer as it uses svg but there is a great library called d3 with a pertinent example here: https://gist.github.com/899711 You may be able to adapt to canvas, for example with something as simple as this: http://www.svgopen.org/2010/papers/62-From_SVG_to_Canvas_and_Back/index.html#canvas_to_svg or something fancier like fabric.js, particularly https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/blob/d42ba6ec027274ed89c8262dfc3935b10e81f479/src/parser.js#L431

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the map bounds method, get the northeast and southwest view of current viewable map and use a js function to modify the overlay on each zoom to change the position dynamically.

```
mapBound = map.getBounds();
northEndOfMap =mapBound.getNorthEast();
```

and to get map zoom
    map.getZoom();
Refer: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map

Comment: Thats similar to what I ended up doing. You get the SouthWest point, minus the height to get the Northwest point, convert it from latlng to pixel and set the canvas top and left attribute to that point. Thank you very much.

Comment: any idea how you would get it to work if the zoom is low enough to actually contain more than one span of the earth, eg [-190, 230]?

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [CanvasLayer](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/#svn/trunk/canvaslayer) library which basically takes all of this into account for you as a reference implementation.